# capturing title and metatags from a textarea

Tags: javascript, xhtml, asp-classic

I am trying to capture html

> `<title></title>`

and `Metadata` from with in a `form1` but not exactly sure how to do it...

My quess is to do it like: `document.write(document.form1.title);` or `document.write.texteara.(document.form1.title);`
but this is not working for me...

```
  <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"><title>This is the title tag extracted</title><meta name="keywords" content="test 1, test 2, test3" /></textarea>
  </label>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= g_page_site_actual %>/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
if (document.getElementsByName) {
  var metaArray = document.getElementsByName('Author');
  for (var i=0; i<metaArray.length; i++) {
    document.write(metaArray[i].content + '<br>');
  }

  var metaArray = document.getElementsByName('Description');
  for (var i=0; i<metaArray.length; i++) {
    document.write(metaArray[i].content + '<br>');
  }

  var metaArray = document.getElementsByName('Keywords');
  for (var i=0; i<metaArray.length; i++) {
    document.write(metaArray[i].content + '<br>');
  }
}
document.write(document.form1.title);
//--></script>
```

Any ideas how I can capture the metadata from within a textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textarea contains a simple string of text. There are no elements or metadata.

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"><title>This is the title tag extracted</title><meta name="keywords" content="test 1, test 2, test3" /></textarea>
```

This is invalid, though browsers typically fix it up for you (until the sequence `</textarea`, anyway). You must HTML-encode `<` and `&` in the content of a `<textarea>` just like all text content and attribute values:

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">&lt;title>This is the title tag extracted&lt;/title>&lt;meta name="keywords" content="test 1, test 2, test3" /></textarea>
```

You'd then read the contents of the textarea with `input.value` as with any other field.

If you want to parse that string value into an HTML document and extract parts of it, you'll need to write it to an element using `element.innerHTML= value` and then use DOM methods to extract data from the element:

```
var el= document.createElement('head');
el.innerHTML= document.getElementById('textarea').value;
alert(el.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.value);
alert(el.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0].content);
```

Unfortunately IE can't do this because it can't set `innerHTML` on `<head>` or many other elements that aren't normal block/inline elements. To get it to work on IE, you'd have to use a complete new document for the content to go into (what a pain):

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe= document.getElementById('iframe');
    var idoc= 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
    idoc.write(document.getElementById('textarea').value);
    idoc.close();
    alert(idoc.title);
    alert(idoc.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0].content);
</script>
```

It seems to me very unlikely that this is a good idea. Can't you have the server-side generate a page that passes information that JavaScript needs to use in a manner more convenient to JavaScript? eg. spit out a JSON-encoded lookup like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var info= {
        "title": "This is the title tag extracted",
        "keywords": ["test 1", "test 2", "test3"]
    };
</script>
```